# RTL language Text in Crystal reports not exporting to PDF correctly

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have Windows Forms VB.NET application developed under VS2005. I am using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2005. The reports has some Arabic and Hebrew text in it. My problem is that although text appears correct in the viewer at run time, when exported to any format including PDF the text appears reversed. The letters appear correctly but the arrangement of the letters in words is reversed and accordingly the word appear incorrectly.

Is there a way to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by selecting text object paragraph right-to-left property.